# Using classes for X number of config files which needs to be read individually in memory

Tags: go

I am working with lot of config files. I need to read all those individual config file in their own struct and then make one giant `Config` struct which holds all other individual config struct in it.

Let's suppose if I am working with 3 config files.

- `ClientConfig` deals with one config file.
- `DataMapConfig` deals with second config file.
- `ProcessDataConfig` deals with third config file.

I created separate class for each of those individual config file and have separate `Readxxxxx` method in them to read their own individual config and return struct back. Below is my `config.go` file which is called via `Init` method from `main` function after passing `path` and `logger`.

**config.go**

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type Config struct {
    ClientMapConfigs   ClientConfig
    DataMapConfigs     DataMapConfig
    ProcessDataConfigs ProcessDataConfig
}

func Init(path string, logger log.Logger) (*Config, error) {
    var err error
    clientConfig, err := ReadClientMapConfig(path, logger)
    dataMapConfig, err := ReadDataMapConfig(path, logger)
    processDataConfig, err := ReadProcessDataConfig(path, logger)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Config{
        ClientMapConfigs:       *clientConfig,
        DataMapConfigs:         *dataMapConfig,
        ProcessDataConfigs:     *processDataConfig,
    }, nil
}
```

**clientconfig.go**

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type ClientConfig struct {
  .....
  .....
}

const (
    ClientConfigFile = "clientConfigMap.json"
)

func ReadClientMapConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*ClientConfig, error) {
  files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, ClientConfigFile)
  // read all the files
  // do some validation on all those files
  // deserialize them into ClientConfig struct
  // return clientconfig object back
}
```

**datamapconfig.go**

Similar style I have for `datamapconfig` too. Exactly replica of `clientconfig.go` file but operating on different config file name and will return `DataMapConfig` struct back.

**processdataConfig.go**

Same thing as `clientconfig.go` file. Only difference is it will operate on different config file and return `ProcessDataConfig` struct back.

**Problem Statement**

I am looking for ideas where this above design can be improved? Is there any better way to do this in `golang`? Can we use interface or anything else which can improve the above design?

If I have let's say 10 different files instead of 3, then do I need to keep doing above same thing for remaining 7 files? If yes, then the code will look ugly. Any suggestions or ideas will greatly help me.

**Note:**
I can do validations after unmarshaling.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, you have a number of JSON files and you want to do lookup/parsing on each file.

Keep in mind that Go is not an "object-oriented" language, and does not have classes. It is a slight conceptual shift to think about structs as data, rather than a way to organize code.

I would write a helper function that takes as arguments the file name and a struct to serialize into. A sketch of the implementation is given below.

```
// ReadConfig reads the specified file and then parses the
// file as JSON into the given config structure.
func ReadConfig(filePath string, config any) error {
    files, err := utilities.FindFiles(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(files) == 0 {
        return errors.New("no files were found")
    }
    fileContent, err := os.ReadFile(files[0])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(fileContent, config)
}

// Then you would call the helper function as follows

func Init(path string) (Config, error) {
    // Parse client map config.
    var clientConfig ClientConfig
    if err := ReadConfig(path+"/clientConfigMap.json", &clientConfig); err != nil {
        return Config{}, err
    }
    if err := ValidateClientMapConfig(clientConfig); err != nil {
        return Config{}, err
    }

    // Parse data map config.
    var dataMapConfig DataMapConfig
    if err := ReadConfig(path+"/dataConfigMap.json", &dataMapConfig); err != nil {
        return Config{}, err
    }
    if err := ValidateDataMapConfig(dataMapConfig); err != nil {
        return Config{}, err
    }

    // and so on for other config types
}
```

The key idea is that `json.Unmarshal` already takes a struct of any type, so we make our helper function also accept an `any` type, and just pass the value straight to `json.Unmarshal`.

I don't think interfaces are a good fit here, as each parsing function has a different type. Interfaces are useful when you have multiple methods with the same name and types, and you need to pick between them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are on the right track when you think of using an `interface`. One way to look at this is to make ReadConfig an interface with methods ReadConfig(); etc...

Comment: yeah can you provide some examples on how can I make my current code better using interfaces and all?